# What is the danger in the last episode of Lost?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

The entire premise of Lost is that if the MIB escapes the Island, he'll kill everyone in the world. But, in the last episode, as he's trying to escape after initiating the destruction of the Island, it turns out he has lost his powers.

So, what is the danger? If MIB is now a mortal, he obviously can't run around killing everyone.

Answer (score 0):

No one knew that, including the Man in Black himself. As explained [in this other answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/did-the-man-in-black-know-he-would-lose-his-powers/8848#8848), he expected to escape the island and retain his powers.